# How to convert from String to Rc<str>?

Tags: rust

Let's say I would like to generate a string using `write!` (it might be called conditionally, inside the loop etc, it's why I prefer `write!` over `format!`) and then use it in multiple places (so I will need some sort of `Rc`, otherwise I can't easily share it between structures). I don't need to change the string after generation, so I think that `Rc<str>` is a good choice (I can avoid indirection that will cause `Rc<String>` that will store a pointer to pointer).

The problem is a conversion between `String` (valid argument for `write!`) and `Rc<str>`:

```
use std::fmt::Write;

pub fn generate() -> Result<Rc<str>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut out = String::new();
    writeln!(out, "Hello {} {}", 1, 2)?; // Just an example
    Ok(Rc::from(out.into_boxed_str()))
}
```

As I understand `Rc::from` performs copying of all character data into a new memory block (because `Box` and `Rc` have different layouts).

Is it possible somehow utilise the knowledge that we will create `Rc` later, so we can avoid copying? Maybe there are possibility to create someting like `String` (at least something that accepted by `write!`), but with a layout compatible with `Rc`?

Comment: You can avoid allocating the `Box` by using the `From<String> for Rc<str>` implementation, I don't think you can avoid copying the data at least once.

Comment: The problem is whatever you're using to create the string has to keep track of both how much memory is allocated (capacity) as well as how much is actually used (length) while `Rc<str>` only keeps track of one, the length.

Comment: You may be able to avoid the copy if you know the exact size ahead of time and you are willing to use unsafe code. But even then I don't think this is possible. And I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I think [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=970151f3f97868afefc37f66ed93d038) does it (if you write only 5 chars, I messed up by using writeln), but like Chayim said it's not recommended. Also my asm-foo is too weak to confirm this doesn't still do a copy I'm not seeing.

Comment: @cafce25 You can use `new_uninit_slice()` if you only know the length at runtime. Your code is also unsound.

Comment: @cafce25 [This is a better playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7210cd0cf6289e8ee7916de7025ff4d6) (also, the length should be 6 for the newline).

Comment: @cafce25 Nope, still unsound. [Here's a sound one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b96963ddc10fcb6ada38428dddf652f8) (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

### With an unknown number of bytes up front

Your best bet is to just use the `From<String>` implementation of `Rc<str>`,
the `String` handles growing and copying while you're still appending and then when you know the amount of memory you need you copy it once over into the `Rc<str>` getting rid of any over allocation.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub fn generate() -> Result<Rc<str>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut out = String::new();
    writeln!(out, "Hello {} {}", 1, 2)?; // Just an example
    Ok(Rc::from(out))
}
```

### With a known number of bytes

You can directly allocate an `Rc` with enough storage to store the whole `str` and copy the data directly into it. To avoid initializing you can use `MaybeUninit`.

This currently requires nightly since there is no way to create an `Rc` with uninitialized storage on stable (that I know of).

```rust
#![feature(new_uninit, read_buf)]
use std::io::BorrowedBuf;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::io::Write;
fn main() {
    let a = "hello";
    let b = "world";
    let len = a.len() + b.len() + 2;
    let mut rc = Rc::<[u8]>::new_uninit_slice(len);
    let mut r = BorrowedBuf::from(Rc::get_mut(&mut rc).unwrap());
    write!(r.unfilled(), "{a} {b}!").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(len, r.len());
    // SAFETY:
    // * we wrote all bytes in the `Rc`
    // * it's guaranteed valid utf-8 because we only used `write!` to do so
    // * layout is the same between `Rc<[u8]>` and `Rc<str>` https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html#single-field-structs
    let rc: Rc<str> = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(rc) };
    dbg!(rc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known length, you can do it even on stable, at the cost of zeroing  the array (and `unsafe` code). This is not guaranteed, but currently works without allocating because [std specializes `Rc`'s `FromIterator` for `TrustedLen` iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.66.0/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#2099), and `Take<Repeat>` is `TrustedLen` (adapted the code from @cafce25's answer):

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Write;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub fn generate() -> Result<Rc<str>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut rc = StrRcBuidler::new(6);
    writeln!(rc, "Hello")?;
    Ok(rc.build().unwrap())
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct StrRcBuidler {
    rc: Rc<[u8]>,
    pos: usize,
}

impl StrRcBuidler {
    fn new(len: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            rc: std::iter::repeat(0).take(len).collect(),
            pos: 0,
        }
    }
    fn build(self) -> Result<Rc<str>, Self> {
        if self.pos < self.rc.len() {
            return Err(self);
        }
        // SAFETY:
        //  - `[u8]` has the same layout as `str`.
        //  - Everything is UTF-8 because we only allow writes with `fmt::Write`.
        //  - We checked above that all bytes are initialized.
        Ok(unsafe { Rc::from_raw(Rc::into_raw(self.rc) as *const str) })
    }
}

impl Write for StrRcBuidler {
    fn write_str(&mut self, i: &str) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> {
        let i = i.as_bytes();
        let data = Rc::get_mut(&mut self.rc).unwrap()[self.pos..]
            .get_mut(..i.len())
            .ok_or(std::fmt::Error)?;
        data.copy_from_slice(i);
        self.pos += i.len();
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Technically, you can use this also with only an upper limit on the length (just omit the `if self.pos < self.rc.len()` check), but this will pad the string with zeroes.