# Why does `Rc` factory methods clone the input's content instead of reusing it?

Tags: optimization, rust

We can call `Rc::from(my_box)` to convert a `Box<T>` into `Rc<T>`, but its implementation is cloning the content into a new buffer `RcBox` instead of reusing the old box.

The only convincing reason I can think of is that bookkeeping variables next to the content make cloning faster. Are there any other concerns? Is there any implementation similar to C++'s `new shared_ptr(old_ptr)`?

```rust
fn from_box(v: Box<T>) -> Rc<T> {
    unsafe {
        let (box_unique, alloc) = Box::into_unique(v);
        let bptr = box_unique.as_ptr();

        let value_size = size_of_val(&*bptr);
        let ptr = Self::allocate_for_ptr(bptr);

        // Copy value as bytes
        ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            bptr as *const T as *const u8,
            &mut (*ptr).value as *mut _ as *mut u8,
            value_size,
        );

        // Free the allocation without dropping its contents
        box_free(box_unique, alloc);

        Self::from_ptr(ptr)
    }
}
```

Other creators also clone the memory instead of reusing the old content, despite the input being moved in.

```rust
impl From<String> for Rc<str> {
    fn from(v: String) -> Rc<str> {
        Rc::from(&v[..])
    }
}
```

Comment: Context: I want to construct an `Rc<str>` from two `&str`s concatenated in place without intermediate allocation.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the `From<String> for Rc<str>` case, the length of the string belongs to the `String` value. To create the `str` it also needs to make room to hold a `usize` next to the actual string contents.

Comment: *"Context: I want to construct an `Rc<str>` from two `&strs` concatenated in place without intermediate allocation."* - not sure if I get this one ... `&str` is a reference, `Rc<str>` is an owned value, how could you ever convert those without cloning? Also, what does *"`&str`'s concatenated in place"* mean?

Comment: @Finomnis I assume they mean that they don't want the intermediate-allocation-which-gets-dropped of e.g. going through a `String`, they would like to perform a single allocation of the correct size and concatenate the two strs into that.

Comment: @Masklinn You were right. I was ambiguous in the description. The ultimate question I wanted to ask is if `Rc` could reuse the input's resource.

Comment: Rel: [How to convert from String to Rc<str>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75046516/how-to-convert-from-string-to-rcstr)

Comment: it's way less opti to have two pointer than one also, have a Rc<Box> is just so rare, I never see it actually

Comment: Note on terminology: the word "clone" is misleading here, as it has a specific meaning in Rust (it's the equivalent of C++'s _copy construction_), and decidedly _doesn't_ occur here. What does occur is a move to a new allocation. While that's not a negligible operation, it's decidedly cheaper than a full clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masklinn is correct. The implementation of `Rc` places the reference counts in the same heap allocation as the pointee. You can't use the `Box` pointee's heap memory for the `Rc` because it doesn't have space for the reference counts.

But I think the core of your question is: "Why is it implemented this way instead of having the pointee and reference counts in 2 separate heap allocations?"

They *could* have implemented it that way. In fact, that's how it's done in C++ `shared_ptr`. This would make it possible to simply initialise the `Rc` to point to the memory from the `Box`, and then the reference counts would be allocated separately.

I can't say for sure why they made the decision they did, but I would hazard a guess that it's a performance tradeoff. Allocating heap memory is quite slow, so it's faster to 1 allocation than 2. Accessing consecutive memory is also much faster than accessing 2 separate regions.

I think an alternative that has reference counts separately would be a useful addition to Rust, so that people can choose whichever is best for their use case.

Comment: Note that the content of the box is not "cloned" into the new `Rc`, at least not in the Rust sense of the word. It's _moved_ there.

Comment: @user4815162342 I guess you meant it was `memcpy`-ed into the `Rc`. Nonetheless, it could still be copying a large chunk of memory.

Comment: I have found some experimental methods such as `new_uninit` and `new_uninit_slice`. I guess they are used for cases where overhead allocation is undesired.

Comment: No they are not. If anything they do the opposite, they *only* allocate. Stop looking for a way, there isn't one because it's not supported, because the data layout itself precludes it.

Comment: @Fifnmar *I guess you meant it was memcpy-ed into the Rc* - yes, in Rust a move is equivalent to a memcpy withouy dropping the original.

Comment: @user4815162342 fair point, I've edited to clarify. Thanks

Comment: An implication of this design is that if one has better decide to use `Rc` from upstream, otherwise downstream code will have to do excessive copy when they find they need a `Rc`.

Answer (score 1):

> We can call `Rc::from(my_box)` to convert a `Box<T>` into `Rc<T>`, but its implementation is cloning the content into a new buffer `RcBox` instead of reusing the old box.

It *can not* reuse the old box, because the two have a different layout:

```rust
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}
```

> The only convincing reason I can think of is that bookkeeping variables next to the content make cloning faster.

There's no need for a "convincing reason", they're straight up not compatible due to the data layout selected for Rust.

> Is there any implementation similar to C++'s new shared_ptr(old_ptr)?

No. C++ shared pointers have two pointers, one to the object and one to the control block. So it's possible for a shared pointer to "adopt" the object pointer as-is, separately allocating a control block to go with.

Rust shared pointers don't, and thus can't.

Comment: I have read the layout of `RcBox`. I wonder the reason for it. After all, we could have made `Rc` contain two elements.

Comment: Worse cache behaviour (though likely less so in Rust than C++ as manipulating the refcount is a more explicit operation), and more allocations in the overwhelmingly common case where you're creating a pointer *de novo*, since refcounting is almost required to share data between threads.

Comment: Copying a large struct of several hundred bytes might be costlier. I believe it should made its user choose as in C++: such as `make_shared` to allocate the buffer together.

Comment: That's nice. Don't hesitate to try pitching it to the core team (though I don't fancy your odds given the ownership issues that would cause). In the meantime, that's not an option.